# node js, tengo problemas con la propiedad path o eso creo

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, framework

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
    at uploadImage (C:\wamp64\www\backend\controllers\project.js:107:44)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\wamp64\www\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\wamp64\www\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Form.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\backend\node_modules\connect-multiparty\index.js:114:7)
    at Form.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:81:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21)
Error: Request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.onReqAborted (C:\wamp64\www\backend\node_modules\multiparty\index.js:190:17)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at abortIncoming (_http_server.js:537:9)
    at socketOnClose (_http_server.js:530:3)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:671:12)
```

<-- este es el codigo del metodo -->

[image: ese es el codigo del metodo]

Comment: Hola, puedes poner el codigo que genera el error?

Comment: no me deja meter el codigo en la pregunta, me dice que no cumple con el formato bla bla, es que es extenso tambien por eso no lo meto aqui en los comentarios. :(

Comment: Al parecer el error esta en la linea `107`. Verifica que `req.files.image` exista con un `console.log`. Si estas usando un middleware para obtener los archivos en `req.files` puede que el nombre no sea `image`.

Comment: ahi te envie la foto donde tengo toda la configuraciones y dentro de ella esta el middleware, no doy con el error aun.

Comment: o sea la foto llega a la base de datos pero, haciendo la prueba en el postman me arroja el siguiente error, que es el mismo que me refleja en la consola que fue el que copie al principio de la pregunta.

Comment: Haz un `console.log` de `req.files` para saber que te esta subiendo y lo publicas en tu respuesta

Comment: La documentación del módulo que usas ([`connect-multiparty`](https://github.com/expressjs/connect-multiparty#readme)) es bastante escueta. Además, ponen directamente: *I actually recommend against using this module. It's cleaner to use the multiparty API directly.*. Por otro lado, haz tal como te sugiere @Legna, muestra un `console.log(req.files)` para saber lo que estás recibiendo. Saludos